# Security exception when trying to run Play

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

My scala version is 2.12.8

I downloaded https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=play&project=play-scala-rest-api-example

Now trying to do : sbt run, but getting following exception.

What is the fix for this? If I'm making mistake every time then maybe something I am missing always.

```
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: The crucial thing in the error message is the "PKIX path building failed" thing, do a search on that and you will find that this is a well-known general JVM issue and has nothing to do with Play or Scala or sbt specifically.

Comment: I have exported certificate from firefox, ran following command and restarted mac, still finding same issue. keytool -import -alias example -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file ~/Desktop/ok.crt

Comment: Did you try to check `SBT` version and Scala Version ?

Comment: at least  JVM 1.8 but I don't think so if it is compatible with java 11